# When creating javascript objects is the "Object" object just created once and just referenced by everything's __proto__?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

When creating javascript objects is the "Object" object just created once and just referenced by everything's proto

Comment: Yes and no. Other objects reference Object.prototype (through their `[[Prototype]]` chain), not Object.

Comment: Yes, multiple objects can inherit from the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the overarching "Object" object is created once and its prototypes are referenced by different JavaScript(JS) objects, such as Array or other created objects. But if you created an object that inherits from another superclass object that you created, its `__proto__` will first reference to the superclass's object prototype in its prototypal chain.

When you create an object and call a method, JS seeks the method by going through the prototypal chain. If JS does not find the method in the object, it will try to delegate the method from the object's superclass. If it still does not find the method, it will delegate up one more level, and eventually to the "Object" object. Suppose you created a Person object as a superclass for Hero object:

```
let Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + ".")
}

let Hero = function(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
}

Hero.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Hero.prototype.constructor = Hero;

Hero.prototype.fight = function(villain) {
    console.log("Hero, " + this.name + ", defeated " + villain + "!");
}
```

In the line `Hero.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`, you allow JS to delegate `Person.prototype` for `Hero.prototype`. Here, `Hero.prototype.__proto__` points to `Person.prototype`. If the method is not found in either `Hero.prototype` or `Person.prototype`, then it will ultimately delegate up to `Object.prototype` that is in its prototypal chain `[[Prototype]]` (@RobG thank you for clarifying this).

Comment: Note that the [use of `__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), so please do not use it. Use [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) instead. The global *Object* has exactly one *prototype* property. ;-)

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I was thinking because creating a new Object totally defeats the whole concept but it's sort of breezed over on all the prototype tutorials.

Comment: Re "*Thus, all JS native objects will reference "Object" object's prototype, but not the objects created by the user.*". All objects created "by the user" using plain ECMAScript methods are native objects, and they all have Object.prototype on their `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Comment: @RobG I understand that the use of `__proto__` is deprecated. So the use of `Object.create(Hero.prototype)` is ultimately using `__proto__`? and it is a bad practice? (@RobG, @girvain). Also, @RobG thank you for pointing out my error. I will edit my post.

Comment: @mikekoo Yes, using `__proto__` is a bad practice

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your comment. I understand that. So I guess it means invoking `Object.create()` uses `__proto__` directly, and so invoking it is a bad practice?

Comment: @mikekoo No, `Object.create` doesn't use the `__proto__` getter/setter at all, it directly accesses the underlying internal [[prototype]] property, just like `Object.getPrototypeOf`, `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `Object.prototype.__proto__` do.

Answer (score 0):

1) An object's `__proto__` property indicates which object was used as the prototype when it was created.

2) Since `__proto__` points to an object, it's a reference, because that's always how objects are stored in JavaScript, by reference.

3) New objects created with `Object.create()` will have a `__proto__` equal to the function argument.  Therefore, not all objects have the same `__proto__`.

4) `Object` is a [built-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) function, defined only once.

5) Object literals have a `__proto__` of `Object.prototype` (not `Object`):

```
const obj = {};
console.log(obj.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

That's because creating an object literal is the same as doing:

```
Object.create(Object.prototype)
```